# Strange errors: EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my class

Tags: c++, ios, llvm

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct TItemSelector{
  ItemSelectFrame* pItems[2];
} SItemSelector;

class item {
  public:
  void expMethod();
  SItemSelector itemSelector_;
  UILayerButton* startBtn_;
};

void item::expMethod(){
startBtn_ = new UILayerButton();
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  itemSelector_.pItems[i] = new ItemSelectFrame();
}
startBtn_->callMethodA();
}

void UILayerButton::callMethodA()
{
  this->callMethodB();
}

void UILayerButton::callMethodB()
{

}
```

On `this->callMethodB();`, a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" occoured.

After that I found a work-around:

```
class item {
  public:
  void expMethod();
  SItemSelector itemSelector_;
  SItemSelector itemSelector2_; // work around
  UILayerButton* startBtn_;
};
```

Then everything goes well... I just don't know what happened, but `callMethodB()` is just an empty method, there's nothing to do with it.

I'm using Apple LLVM 3.1, default setting.

UPDATE: Fixed my code.

Comment: Uh, what's "strange" about EXC_BAD_ACCESS?  You used an invalid pointer somewhere.  (Where do you set startBtn_?)

Comment: Sry I missed one line, fixed. @HotLicks

Comment: Hard to tell from what you posted. Could you add the definition of `UILayerButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  itemSelector_.pItems[i] = new ItemSelectFrame();
}
```

you are writing over the end of `itemSelector_.pItems` because `pItems` is an array of length `2` but you are writing `3` elements.

That then overwrites `startBtn_` which happens to appear immediately after `itemSelector_` in memory. And that explains the error when you subsequently read the now corrupted `startBtn_`.

Either change your loop termination test, or increase the length of `pItems`. I can't tell which one is the correct solution, but clearly you will know.

Comment: @Syhou -- It's not "stupid" to make such a mistake, it's merely human.  The "stupid" part is to so fixate on where you THINK the error is (and, worse, to be "positive" that the error is in system code) rather than to consider all the places where the error MIGHT be.